# Why is "de" used instead of "des" in the following sentence?

Tags: de

Plus vous l’écouterez, plus vous comprendrez de choses.

I came across this one in the transcript of text for a podcast, and I am wondering why it is"de choses", not "des choses".

Comment: @Reyedy The post you proposed is specifically about the use of "besoin de", a phrase after which nouns do not need any articles. i don't think my question is about any such phrases, but if you do have some insight, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: What is interesting in the post I linked is Luke's answer. He gives examples where it's not only about "besoin". One of his examples is "plus de livres". The idea is that you don't need the article after a quantity because you are talking about an indefinite noun ("choses"). If you added the article, the meaning would change to "more of the things" instead of simply "more things", making it less abstract and relating to a definite amount of "choses".

Comment: @Reyedy wow, I did not think of it in the way of "plus de". Now that you mentioned it, it seems to make a lot of sense. My bad!